# javascript error with php variable passing in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

```
function something(frm,i){
//var ch=frm.outof1.value;
for(var j=1;j<=i;j++)
{
    //var b="outof" + j;
    alert(frm.outof+j.value);

}
//alert("outof" + i);
return false;
}

 $js='onClick="something(this.form,\''. $ii .'\')"';
  echo form_button('mybutton', 'Click Me', $js);
```

and getting output NAN
where in html this is // echo form_input('outof'.$i,''); // the form input.

Comment: I think this may belong in the cryptography forum.

Comment: i need value of form input named outof1,outof2...etc...but i am getting output NaN

Comment: Can you post your rendered HTML here that browser get by this `echo form_button('mybutton', 'Click Me', $js);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will want to make sure the passed `$ii` is made into the correct type (not a string) by using `parseInt`. Then you construct the form input name by concatenating `'outof'` and the number before evaluating `.value`.

```
function something(frm, i)
{
    for(var j = 1; j <= parseInt(i); ++j) {
        alert(frm['outof' + j].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, however `i` should expect an integer versus having to convert it within the method. Probably unquote that second arg. Agree?

Comment: @MattLo I normally pass verbatim variables to JavaScript using `json_encode` to make sure the intended type is passed without causing a parse error if the type was anything else :)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(parseInt(frm.outof) + parseInt(j.value))
```

Most likely, you're trying to sum up strings, and not integers